# A basic question on Riemann sum

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, riemann-sum

Suppose $f$ is a non-negative Riemann integrable function in $[a,b]$. Is this true that $$ \sup_P \sum_{j=1}^{n} |f(c_j)(x_j-x_{j-1})| = \int_{a}^{b} |f(x)|dx$$

where $c_j \in [x_{j-1}, x_j]$. I don't think so. But in the definition of bounded variation it is used http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Basic_properties

Comment: It is, because $|f(c_j)(x_j-x_{j-1})| = |f(c_j)|(x_j-x_{j-1})$, and this gives the integral of $|f|$. The variation measures $|f(x_j)-f(x_{j-1})|$ (and this is $|f'(c_j)| (x_j-x_{j-1})$ for some $c_j$ which leads to the integral of $|f'|$), if you will excuse my sloppiness.

Comment: No, it only gives the integral of $|f|$ when the limit as $n\to\infty$ is taken (and the partition mesh size tends to $0$). For a fixed $n$, it's almost guaranteed that the left-hand side as written is larger than the right-hand side. It would be a different story if it were a lim sup as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @copper.hat: Consider a partition for which the sum in the left hand side is higher than the integral in the right hand side (which is possible as $c_j$ need not the infimum of $f$ in that interval here) then sup will be at least that value.

Comment: @GregMartin: Even if I take supremum over all partitions still I think this not true becasue $c_j$'s are not infimum.

Comment: @aaaaaa: I misinterpreted your question. I thought you were wondering why it was $|f|$ and not $|f'|$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \sup_P \sum_{j=1}^{n} |f(c_j)|\cdot(x_j-x_{j-1}) = (b-a)\cdot\sup_{[a,b]}|f|$$
Proof: For every positive $\varepsilon$, consider a partition with $(x_0,x_1,x_2)=(a,u,b)$, $|f(u)|\geqslant\sup\limits_{[a,b]}|f|-\varepsilon$, and $c_1=c_2=u$.

The only case when such $u$ do not exist is when the supremum is reached at $a$ or $b$, then a subdivision into the unique interval $(a,b)$ does the job. QED.

> But in the definition of bounded variation it is used

Is it? Where?

Comment: Then the wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Basic_properties is wrong. Correct ?

Comment: No it is not (bis repetita). Why do you think it is? More specifically, where is the WP page considering the supremum in your question?

Comment: Actually, I am not understanding why total variation of a function is equal to the integral of the modulus of its deriavtive.

Comment: Ahh but this is an entirely different question...

Comment: @aaaaaa: Maybe I didn't misinterpret your intent after all...

Answer (score 0):

Under suitable smoothness hypotheses on $f$, if $P$ is a partition, then for some $c_i \in (x_{i-1}, x_i)$ you have
$\sum_P |f(x_i) -f(x_{i-1})| = \sum_P |f'(c_i)(x_i -x_{i-1})| = \sum_P |f'(c_i)|(x_i -x_{i-1})$,
hence
$L(|f'|,P) \le \sum_P |f(x_i) -f(x_{i-1})| \le U(|f'|,P)$.

Taking $\sup $ over all partitions gives $\int |f'| \le \operatorname{var} f$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ and select partitions $P_1,P_2$ so that
$\operatorname{var} f -\epsilon < \sum_P_1 |f(x_i) -f(x_{i-1})|$ and
$U(|f'|,P_2) < \int |f'| + \epsilon$. Now let $P'$ refine both $P_1,P_2$, then
\begin{eqnarray}
\operatorname{var} f -\epsilon &<& \sum_{P_1} |f(x_i) -f(x_{i-1})| \\
&\le& \sum_{P'} |f(x_i) -f(x_{i-1})| \\
&\le& U(|f'|,P') \\
&\le& U(|f'|,P_2) \\
&<& \int |f'| + \epsilon
\end{eqnarray}
from which we get $\operatorname{var} f \le \int |f'|$.

**Note**: the first line is from the selection of $P_1$. The second line is because $P'$ refines $P_1$, and the triangle inequality. The third line follows from the mean value theorem. The fourth line follows because $P'$ is a refinement of $P_2$, and the last from the selection of $P_2$.

Comment: understood the proof. But, if $var f \leq \int |f'|$ then necessarily $\sum_P |f'(c_j)|(x_j-x_{j-1}) \leq U(P',f')$ for any two partitions $P$ and $P'$. Why is this true ? Taking a common refinement I can't proceed.

Comment: It is not true for any two partitions. $P'$ is a refinement of both $P_1,P_2$. Since $P'$ refines $P_1$, we have $\sum_{P_1} \cdots \le \sum_{P'} \cdots$ and since $P'$ refines $P_2$, we have $U(-,P') \le U(-,P_2)$.